# How do I copy file from docker container to dockerfile building stage

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to copy some files from another docker container to my dockerfile building stage like this.

```
FROM linux/optimize as building_stage
COPY {container_id}:/some_file /var/root
```

I have tried specifying **container_id** but it didn't work. how can I copy file from another container?

Comment: How does the file get into the other container?  What you're describing sounds not dissimilar to a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/); could you use this to `RUN` the command to generate the file in an earlier build stage, then `COPY --from` the earlier stage into the final image?

Comment: @DavidMaze it's not multi-stage build actually. it's a file that I need from another container in order to build. maybe use RUN "curl -get $filepath" would work too?

Answer (score 1):

Copying from running container to image [does not seem possible](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/docker-copying-files#dockerfile-copy).

Two ways this can be achieved

1. If some_file exists in the image (not created by container)

```
COPY --from=<Image Name>:<tag> /some_file /var/root
```

2. some_file was created after container creation (docker run): copy some_file from container volumes,

```
COPY /container/volume/with/some_file /var/root
```

If the volume is not known then just copy some_file to . before `docker build`

Dockerfile

```
FROM linux/optimize as building_stage
COPY ./some_file /var/root
```

```
docker cp SOME_FILE_CONTAINER:/some_file .
docker build
```